# C# Generic Class<T>

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, addition

How can I add a generic Type to my list?
I tried to create an object of T but this doesn't work neither.

```
class Bar<T> where T : IDrink
{
    List<T> storage = new List<T>();

    public void CreateDrink()
    {
        storage.Add(T); //<- This doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: try `storage.Add(default(T));`

Comment: Using `default(T)` will not create an instance of `T`, it will give `null` for reference types and the default value for value types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` is a type not an instance of that type. So you need a parameter in `CreateDrink` or use a factory method that returns a new instance of `T`.

If you want to create an instance the generic constraint must include [`new()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

```
class Bar<T> where T : IDrink, new()
{
    List<T> storage = new List<T>();

    public void CreateDrink()
    {
        storage.Add(new T()); 
    }
}
```

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like:

```
storage.Add(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
```